# how to custom profile pic input like facebook

Tags: html, css

I would like to custom my profile pic like in this picture but I can't, don't know what's wrong.
I have an external bootstrap CSS file though. What I want to follow the Facebook profile pice update design but facing small issue, I have attached a pic to see how I want it
[image: profile pic snippet]
HTML

```
<div class="user-thumb user-thumb--edit">
    <div class="custom-file">
        <input class="custom-file__input" id="photo" accept="image/*" type="file">
            <label class="custom-file__label" for="photo">
                <img alt="" class="thumb--lg rounded-circle" src="">
            </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
.user-thumb {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #e9e9e9;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.user-thumb--edit {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
.custom-file {
    margin: 0;
    height: auto;
}
.custom-file__input {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
}
.custom-file__label {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 1rem;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: transparent;
    position: relative;
}
.user-thumb--edit .custom-file__label::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 20;
    background: #ffffff url();
    background: 1.4rem auto;
    width: 4.2rem;
    height: 4.2rem;
    border-radius: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 6px 6px -3px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%), 0px 10px 14px 1px rgb(0 0 0 / 14%), 0px 4px 18px 3px rgb(0 0 0 / 12%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this if you set the `border-radius` of the label to `50%` instead of `0` and add `overflow: hidden`, which would also hide a part of the `::before`. Therefor you should define that `::before` not for the label but for the containing div: `.custom-file::before`.

**Working example:**

```css
.user-thumb {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #e9e9e9;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.user-thumb--edit {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.custom-file {
  margin: 0;
  height: auto;
}

.custom-file__input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
}

.custom-file__label {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1rem;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 0;
  background: transparent;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.user-thumb--edit .custom-file::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 20;
  background: #ffffff url();
  background: 1.4rem auto;
  width: 4.2rem;
  height: 4.2rem;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 6px -3px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%), 0px 10px 14px 1px rgb(0 0 0 / 14%), 0px 4px 18px 3px rgb(0 0 0 / 12%);
}
```

```html
<div class="user-thumb user-thumb--edit">
  <div class="custom-file">
    <input class="custom-file__input" id="photo" accept="image/*" type="file">
    <label class="custom-file__label" for="photo">
      <img alt="" class="thumb--lg rounded-circle" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```